# Thread 1 Sigabrt error xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, lldb, sigabrt

I have a app that shows a RSSI and some other stuff from a Beacon. As you all know, the RSSI is being visible for the user by showing it in a tableView which updates every second (Very fast). In the tableView i call a class, who is doing some stuff. The class is calculating, and the calculations is taking some seconds. The error i get is lldb. When i type bt i get these information.

```
* thread #1: time = 0x3d0fd, 0x0000000197c07140 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 8, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGABRT
    frame #0: 0x0000000197c07140 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 8
    frame #1: 0x0000000197cd0ef8 libsystem_pthread.dylib`pthread_kill + 112
    frame #2: 0x0000000197b7ac18 libsystem_c.dylib`__abort + 148
    frame #3: 0x0000000197b7b494 libsystem_c.dylib`__stack_chk_fail + 224
  * frame #4: 0x00000001000eae98 ssProject`-[myClass ft:::](self=0x000000014e9320f0, _cmd="ft:::", size=2048, startRing=0, ringArray=@"2837 objects") + 1380 at myClass:173
    frame #5: 0x00000001000eb4ec ssProject `-[myClass cl::](self=0x000000014e9320f0, _cmd="cl::", allR=@"514 objects", allT=@"514 objects") + 1620 at myClass:260
    frame #6: 0x00000001000e2034 ssProject `-[TagViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:](self=@"0 objects", _cmd="tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:", tableView=0x0000000148828c00, indexPath=0xc000000000000016) + 1624 at TagViewController.m:184
    frame #7: 0x00000001880ba20c UIKit`-[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 688
    frame #8: 0x00000001880ba364 UIKit`-[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:willDisplay:] + 80
    frame #9: 0x00000001880a97b8 UIKit`-[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] + 2440
    frame #10: 0x00000001880bef0c UIKit`-[UITableView _performWithCachedTraitCollection:] + 104
    frame #11: 0x0000000187e5722c UIKit`-[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 176
    frame #12: 0x0000000187d677ac UIKit`-[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 644
    frame #13: 0x0000000187566b58 QuartzCore`-[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 148
    frame #14: 0x0000000187561764 QuartzCore`CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 292
    frame #15: 0x0000000187561624 QuartzCore`CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 32
    frame #16: 0x0000000187560cc0 QuartzCore`CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 252
    frame #17: 0x0000000187560a08 QuartzCore`CA::Transaction::commit() + 512
    frame #18: 0x000000018755a0f8 QuartzCore`CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 80
    frame #19: 0x000000018278fbd0 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
    frame #20: 0x000000018278d974 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoObservers + 372
    frame #21: 0x000000018278dda4 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 928
    frame #22: 0x00000001826bcca0 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
    frame #23: 0x000000018d8f8088 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 180
    frame #24: 0x0000000187dd4ffc UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 204
    frame #25: 0x00000001000e9680 swimsimulator`main(argc=1, argv=0x000000016fd27ae8) + 116 at main.m:14
    frame #26: 0x0000000197aea8b8 libdyld.dylib`start + 4
```

I hope anybody of you can help me with the problem.

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Tag"];

        AXABeacon *beacon = [[AXABeacon alloc] init];
        beacon = [self.bleDevices objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        //Definerar veriabler
        UILabel *titleLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
        UILabel *uuidLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
        UILabel *rssiLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:3];
        UILabel *majorLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:4];
        UILabel *minorLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:5];
        UILabel *statusLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:6];
        UILabel *lastLap = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:7];
        UILabel *lastTime = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:8];

        //Ger variabler ett värde
        titleLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", beacon.name];
        uuidLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", beacon.uuidString];
        rssiLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"RSSI: %@", [beacon.rssi stringValue]];
        minorLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Minor: %@", beacon.minor];
        majorLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Major: %@", beacon.major];

        NSString *fileNameWithDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d.csv", beacon.uuidString, self.randNum];
        NSMutableArray *allRssis = [self getDataInArray: @"rssi":fileNameWithDate];
        NSMutableArray *allTimes2 = [self getDataInArray: @"time":fileNameWithDate];

        NSInteger bitar = 257;
        NSInteger raknBitar = bitar * self.delayCount;

        if(allRssis.count >= raknBitar){
            self.checkAlgo = true;
            NSLog(@"Här kör vi igen");
            if (self.checkAlgo == true) {
                myClass *newObject;
                newObject = [[myClass alloc] init];
                self.checkAlgo = false;
                self.delayCount = self.delayCount + 1;
                NSLog(@"%@", [newObject cl:allR :allT]);
 [result objectAtIndex:0]];
                //lastTime.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Tiden (Senaste): %@", [result objectAtIndex:1]];
            }
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Antal rader: %lu", (unsigned long)allTimes2.count);
        }

        if(self.startClicked)
        {
            statusLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Status: Lagrar data"];
        }
        else
        {
            statusLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Status:"];
        }
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

        //Anpassar text till storlek av box
        uuidLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
        titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;

        return cell;
    }
```

Comment: There's no point to updating a table view faster than the display's refresh rate (60 Hz)

Comment: Could you update your post with the code that you're getting the `sigabrt` thrown on?

Comment: I have added the code to the question @Chris

Comment: Where does the sigabrt occur?

Answer (score 1):

That you're failing with a stack_chk_fail means you're overwriting some variable that's on the stack.  The way this works is that the compiler inserts a guard word in the stack at the start of a call, and when you come back from the call it checks to see that that word still has the value it was given.  It didn't, so the stack guard mechanism forced an abort.

For this sort of thing the Address Sanitizer (ASAN) is a good tool to use.  You turn it on in the Diagnostics tab of the Run Scheme for your project.  Then you have to do a rebuild to use it - so the error has to be in code you own.  But if you can use it, it is quite good at catching these sorts of errors when they occur, which makes diagnosis much easier than catching some side effect of the error sometime later.